# Truncate table in Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, entity

I've got an ADO.NET entity data model in my C# project (.NET 3.5) and am using it quite happily. I'd like to be able to truncate the tables in this model.  I've searched online and most suggest using "ExecuteCommand" but my data context doesn't show ExecuteCommand as a usable method.  What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using Entity Framework rather than Linq to SQL? - try `ExecuteStoreCommand`

Comment: Just realised when I went back to look at my project.  But yes, I was.  Having a dumb day.  :)

Comment: @LajosArpad He can't - there's a time delay limit.